# Where can I setup a company in Europe to register a car/campervan?

Tags: europe, registration, campers

So basically, I am Maltese [EU] resident and I would like to purchase a campervan to travel around Europe but the registration tax for a campervan from the EU here is 50% of evaluated value according to local authorities. Even if you buy a van for 10k they can evaluate you for much higher and you have to pay half of that which is pretty absurd.

I know in France [ around 3.5k] it is possible to setup a company to register you car/campervan and same thing in Bulgaria [bulgarianplates.com - around 1.2k in total] - how trust worthy is the service in Bulgaria? Are there any other countries that offer such services?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Setting up a company can be fast and easy. But you then need to run it (which means a business bank account, accounting, filing and paying taxes…). All of that takes time and money. Also, a business must actually be a business (I.e. have an activity). Creating a company just to be the owner of a campervan will probably end up being a nightmare. Of course service providers will forget to tell you all of that, but since you would be a professional you would not qualify for many of the protections a consumer would have.

Comment: Just be aware that you are basically talking about tax evasion at worst, tax avoidance at best - and most EU countries come down on either like a tonne of bricks, and many tax avoidance schemes have been made illegal over the past decade.  You may not ultimately avoid the taxation, and you may even end up with a criminal record in addition.  Be very very careful.

Comment: @jcaron I’m only familiar with Czech Republic - over there running a non-functional company is pretty easy and costs something like 200 euros per year in accounting fees. And there’s no legal requirement for the company to have any business. So I’d avoid giving OP scary advice unless you’re personally familiar with a particular country’s legal system.

Comment: @JonathanReez better safe than sorry… OP specifically mentioned France where this is unlikely to work. There’s actually another reason it won’t: purchases made by the company must be in the interest of the business (which it isn’t here), so the acquisition of the camper van by the company will be deemed a benefit in kind (“abus de bien social”), which will in the best case lead to additional taxation and in the worst case to fines and more. The only types of companies that can hold assets on behalf of the members are _sociétés civiles_, but they’re quite limited (SCI for real estate, mostly).

Comment: So the company would own a camper van and *rent* it to you? In some parts of the EU, it would be required to *try* and make a profit, at least in the long run ... charge you with more than owning the van costs the company. Then it would have to pay taxes on that operation.

Comment: are you asking for tax evasion advice?